# Should I remove normal Java before install Java Development Kit?

Tags: java

I have normal java installed already. now I want to install a software which requires the 2:

1. Java Development Kit 6 or higher (http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)
2. Maven 2.2.1 or higher (http://maven.apache.org/)

Should I remove normal java to install the Development Kit?

Comment: Do you mean JRE by "normal Java"?

Comment: JDK contains JRE so you can remove your old JRE or not - it's just your choice. Maven is a separate thing not included within JRE nor JDK.

Comment: Normal java?? You mean jre?..It provides java runtime environment and will cause no harm. If its a development kit, still no need to remove, just provide the path of the Correct bin folder.

Comment: probably I meant JRE, that's everybody need to install in order to have java shows up in browser :-)

Comment: You can have as many versions of Java installed as your wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not have to. However JDK contains the runtime environment (JRE), so if you can safely remove it, if you wish so.

EDIT: Although, as Johannes points out, you may need to take care of PATH environment variable and file associations on Windows.

Comment: Not entirely correct. Installation of the JDK (atleast on windows) is noninvasive in that it does not mess with the PATH or file associations. So you cannot remove the JRE and install the JDK and expect everything to work.

Comment: 10x, for noticing that. Updated the answer with your note.